# How to get last resolved promise from a list of resolved promises in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Suppose, we have list of promises `[p1,p2]`.
I want to create a function which takes `[p1,p2]` as arguments and return the last resolved promise i.e in this case, the returned promise would be `p2`.

The Motivation is I want to implement last() method on Promise object.

```
 const p1 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                setTimeout(()=>{resolve("P1 resolved in 3 seconds")},3000)
            });
 const p2 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                setTimeout(()=>{resolve("P2 resolved in 5 seconds")},5000)
            });

Promise.race([p2,p1]).then(value=>{ console.log(value) // Both promises resolved but P2 is slower
    }) // Expected output : P1 resolved in 3 seconds

 Promise.last([p2,p1]).then(value=>{ console.log(value) // Both promises resolved but P2 is slower
    }) // Expected output : P2 resolved in 5 second.
```

Comment: My motivation is to create a method last() on Promise object, which will return last resolved promise. For Example  Promise.last([p2,p1]).then(value=>{ console.log(value) // Both promises resolved but P2 is slower}) // Expected output : "P2 resolved in 5 second"

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple: just wait for all the promises using standard `Promise.all`, and put them into an array in the order they fulfilled (when they fulfill) so that you can access the last value:

```
async function lastResult(promises) {
    if (!promises.length) throw new RangeError("No last result from no promises");
    const results = [];
    await Promise.all(promises.map(p =>
        p.then(v => {
            results.push(v);
        })
    ));
    return results[results.length-1];
}
```

You can adjust this to handle rejections in the way you want, to return any other (e.g. first) result, etc. If you really need only the last result, you don't need to store them in an array but can simply keep a single variable that you overwrite every time a promise resolves.

Comment: Promise.race([p2,p1]).then(value=>{ console.log(value) // Both promises resolved but P2 is slower
}) // Expected output : P1 resolved in 3 second Similarly I want  Promise.last([p2,p1]).then(value=>{ console.log(value) // Both promises resolved but P2 is slower
}) // Expected output : P2 resolved in 5 second. But your code result is not as I expected

Comment: @alokkumar please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67339630/edit) to include further code, where you can use formatting. Also did you confuse `Promise.all` with `Promise.race`?

Comment: Please see the updated  question. I think you can understand now, what I am expecting to do.

Comment: @alokkumar Yes, and the code from my answer solves that problem, no? `lastResult([p2,p1]).then(value=>{ console.log(value) })` does print "*P2 resolved in 5 seconds*" as expected.

Comment: Yes, this is working. But I haven't understood why you are using Promise.all(). Could you please explain the flow. I understood, why you are appending the results array. But not understood why we are passing promises.map() inside Promise.all() method.

Comment: We need to wait until all results are in before we can determine which one was last.