# Ordering promis by execution time

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Hello is there any solution to order promises by execution time? for ex

```
Promise.all([Promise // 5ms ,Promise // 3ms,Promise // 2ms])
```

will return answer with same order as it was given is there any solution or method to sort it by execution time to have return like?

```
Promise.all([Promise // 2ms ,Promise // 3ms,Promise // 5ms])
```

Comment: So how would it know execution time? Are you turning it?

Comment: by simulating execution time using for ex `setTimeout(() => resolve('Promis'), 3000);`

Comment: But the promise does not have the execution time. So you would have to attack this in a whole different manner.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67339832/1048572) for inspiration

Comment: @epascarello You don't need the execution time. All you need is the order in which the callbacks are called on the different promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restate the problem clearly: given a set of promises, can they be executed concurrently, and can the results be arranged in an array in order of execution time?

If the execution time is known in advance, then sort the promises by execution time and pass the sorted array to `Promise.all()`.

If the execution times are unknown in advance, I'd suggest wrapping the promises with a little function that times execution. Sort the result of `Promise.all()` on those elapsed times...

```js
function sortedPromiseAll(array) {
  const start = new Date()
  const instrumentPromise = p => {
    return p.then(result => {
      const now = new Date();
      return { result, duration: now.getTime()-start.getTime() }
    });
  }
  const instrumentedPromises = array.map(instrumentPromise)
  return Promise.all(instrumentedPromises).then(results => {
    return results.sort((a, b) => a.duration-b.duration).map(r => r.result);
  })
}

const timedPromise = t => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, t)
  })
};

// imagine we don't know these timings
const promiseA = timedPromise(600).then(() => 'A');
const promiseB = timedPromise(300).then(() => 'B');
const promiseC = timedPromise(900).then(() => 'C');

// expected result is B, A, C
sortedPromiseAll([promiseA, promiseB, promiseC])
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: I'd even recommend to move the `const start = new Date()` outside of the `instrumentPromise` function so that there's only one start date shared by all instrumentations.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks, @Bergi.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ordering of when they resolve if you manually push the results of each promise into an array. In this example the value resolved is a string that shows the timestamp it was added.

Results are pushed into `outputs` array when they resolve. Printing `outputs` shows they are now ordered based on when they resolved.

```js
const outputs = [];

function createPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // adding a bit of randomness here so there is no guarantee when they resolve
    const delay = Math.random() * 1000;
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Promise resolved at ${Date.now()}`);
    }, delay);
  });
}

function addResult() {
  return createPromise().then(value => {
    outputs.push(value);
  });
}

Promise.all([addResult(), addResult()]).then(() => console.log(outputs));
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in `addResult`!

Comment: @Bergi If `addResult` was nothing more than calling `createPromise` I would agree. However, this setup is intention to populate `outputs`.

Comment: So? You still don't need a `new Promise` to do `outputs.push(value)` in a `.then()` callback.

Comment: If `createPromise` is used elsewhere, automatically adding its result to output may be undesired in those other locations. If its only purpose is in this body, the updating of `outputs` can certainly be adjusted.

Comment: I never said to modify the code of `createPromise`. You should just drop the `new Promise` from `addResult` and simply `return createPromise().then(value => { outputs.push(value); });`

Comment: @Bergi I misunderstood, thanks for clarifying. Adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to push them to a new array as they come in. No need to create extra promises, just have to piggyback off the promise that is already created.

```js
const getRandomPromise = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var ms = Math.random() * 3000;
    window.setTimeout(()=>resolve(ms), ms);
  });
};


function orderPromises (promises) {
  const orderedPromies = [];
  const pushPromiseResults = promise =>
    promise.then(result => (orderedPromies.push(result), result))

  promises.forEach(pushPromiseResults);
  return Promise.all(promises).then(()=>orderedPromies);
}

const myPromises = [getRandomPromise(), getRandomPromise(), getRandomPromise()];

orderPromises(myPromises).then(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Using `forEach` instead of `map` and ignoring the promises resulting from the `.then()`calls instead of calling `Promise.all` on them will cause unhandled rejections if any of the promises rejects.